# Ruby on Rails change background colour in CSS according to database

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to allow the user to choose their colour and have this as the sites background.

In my schema I have this preferences table:

```
create_table "perferences", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.text     "colour"
end
```

The CSS background colour is in the following line:

```
body{line-height:1;height:100%;width:100%;color:#B2BFCB;background:#002952;text-align:center;font-family:"Apercu Regular", Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

But I am unsure as to how to update the colour based upon the colour in the database.

I have tried to follow this link: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/18/simpler-than-dirt-restful-dynamic-css
But I got the error: `undefined method formatted_colour_path for #<#<Class:0x6daa0a8>:0x6881b98>`

In the view:

In the perferences controller:

```
def show
   @colour = Perference.find_by(user_id: session[:user_id]).colour
   respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.css
   end
end
```

Can someone please help. I understand that I need to retrieve the colour from the database and then use this to update the CSS, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: it is `formatted_user_path(@user` why are you getting `formatted_colour_path` this error, can you post soem more code

Comment: Sorry I should have added that in, please see the updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to change the body background color, then try this:

```
<body style="background-color: <%= @colour %>">

</body>
```

But it will make some consequences for you and you will need to go deeper :)

It will be better to do it this way

```
<body style="background-color: <%= @colour if @colour %>" >

</body>
```

or just write a helper.

Comment: When you say 'consequences' do you mean I'll just have to validate it?

Comment: Yes. If you will open index or any other page without user and color he had choose. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The css file is fixed - you cannot put ruby code inside. An alternative is to do something inline in your application.html.erb:

```
  <body style="background-color:<%= current_user.preference.color">
  </body>
```

This of course suppose that the user is always loaded in the "current_user" variable (you can use a condition to treat the "not logged in" case).

Comment: Can you please show me how to do this. I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: This might be me being thick, but that gives the error: `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`

Comment: you shown us a "user preferences" table, but how are you signin in your users? Using devise?

Comment: I have a separate user table and they sign in through the bcrypt gem

Comment: and how to you access normally a user preference in one of you page?

Comment: At the minute there is a `link_to` the user can use, this will take them to the preferences index and from there they can add a new preference. This will be changed eventually though to prevent wrong changes.